# hovering effects only to its element

Tags: html, css

```
+----------------------+
|  +--------------+    |
|  +this is a link+    |
|  +--------------+    |
+----------------------+
```

As above drawing, I would like to make a link but want to give hovering effects only to my "this is a link" not to spacer (padding value) of this box has.

html

```
<a href="#">this is a link</a>
```

css

```
a{display: block; width: 350px; padding: 10px; background: red; color: yellow;}
```

Comment: Which effect do you want to create?

Comment: hover effect only to "this is a link" without changing my tag/

Comment: @user2253835 You'd have to inject some javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you have a div around the link and give the padding/margin to the div. The link inside would then be clickable but the div would not. This is probably the easiest solution if you are able to change the html code (and not limited to css)

html

```
<div class="awrapper"><a href="#">this is a link</a></div>
```

css

```
.awrapper{display: block; width: 350px; padding: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `border`, without `padding`.

```
a {
    background: red; 
    display: block; 
    width: 350px;
    color: yellow;
    border: 10px solid red;
}

a:hover {
    border: 10px solid white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y86sV/3/

Comment: @user2253835 It doesn't removes the border, just set white color on the borders when you hover over the link. That is effect you want? _I would like to make a link but want to give hovering effects only to my "this is a link" not to spacer_

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you can't do that.